# Terminator can't find Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, terminal, terminator

I started using Terminator, the teminal emulator, but when I run a rails application it can't find Rails.

```
humberto@asterix:~$ rails -v
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * rails
 * ruby-railties-3.2
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Are you using rbenv or rvm? Are you sure your gem paths are available in your current shell environment?

Comment: I'm using RVM. I think my problem is with the gem path, as you said. How can I set the gem paths on the Terminator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Ensure RVM is Properly Loaded

I don't know anything about your terminal emulator, but it's likely that your environment isn't being properly modified for use by RVM. Make sure your shell sources a file that contains the following:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Depending on your shell and emulator, this is likely to be one of:

- ~/.profile
- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.bashrc

If all else fails, just create a shell script that contains the necessary line and source it interactively into the *current* shell. For example, you might create a script and then `source ~/bin/my_rvm_setup.sh` to set up the correct environment variables and shell functions.

Comment: +1 ... and then I've done: "rvm use 1.9.2@thenameofmygemset" and it was all good!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run terminator from default gnome terminal by the command:

```
terminator
```

Than terminator will load paths defined for your default terminal. You can also load RVM on .bashrc file. To do that add this line on your ~/.bashrc file:

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"